# I need help in interpreting the NPM ERESOLVE error message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I received the following error from NPM when I tried to run npm install on a project I had just cloned. Can anyone explain to me how to interpret this error message? I am not at all sure about which dependency npm is complaining about nor the route it has taken to source those values. I don't even know whether this error message is meant to be read from the bottom up like a stack trace.
This is the error message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-code@0.3.0
npm ERR! Found: @types/react@17.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.9.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"4.9.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6" from @material-ui/icons@4.9.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!   @material-ui/icons@"4.9.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received this error message today. Here are my findings...

Issue: One or more dependencies mentioned in your package.json updated their peer dependency recently. Due to this npm encountered a conflict while resolving the dependency tree (even before downloading packages)

Solution: Ensure that "peer dependencies" don't have difference in "major version"

In your case @types/react@17.0.3 is mentioned in package.json. But @material-ui/icons@4.9.1 needs @types/react@"^16.8.6".

you can either upgrade @material-ui/icons

```
@material-ui/icons: "4.9.1" ---> @material-ui/icons: "^4.9.1"
```

or downgrade react types to version 16

Answer (score 1):

Change the node version to 12.14.1 in Dockerfile it will Work

```
FROM node:12.14.1-alpine
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `package-lock.json` file and the `node_modules` folder and then run `npm i` again. Or you can consider using [yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/) as it doesn't cause problems.

Comment: Well, considering that I was doing this from a clone there wasn't, and because of this error  there still isn't, a `node_modules` folder. I had also made sure that there wasn't a `package-lock.json` file. Given all that, you will understand the desire to be able to interpret the error message

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Run the above command instead of npm install, you will not get any error.